# Passing parameter from jsf to bi publisher report

Tags: java, oracle, jsf, bi-publisher

I've been trying to solve one tricky problem. How does one pass a parameter, say, an integer from jsf page to the actual bi report?

In more detail:

[jsf page]---backing bean takes parameter(an id)---?--- bi report with parameter input(id)

So far, I tried one approach, which simply was using Javascript to pass the value to the input field and 'click' the search button on the page where bi report is inserted via iframe. The obstacle was **same domain policy**, couldn't get/set the insides of iframe.

Is there any way that a parameter can be passed to BI report?

Full scenario:

1. User selects a contract
2. Upon selection, the id of contract is stored in variable in managed bean
3. When the user clicks the "Info Sheet" button, a new page is loaded with iframe
4. iframe contains link to different domain
5. page with BI Report is loaded and there is the input field for contract id that actually needs to be already passed from managed bean.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe passing such parameter to IFrame should be done on the page on server. Not with javascript.

According to full scenario this is what should have worked but it is not. I believe the managedbean scope is lost and that is why the id is not set on different page. To make this work probably the scope of managed bean should be session not request or view because you go to different page.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @trims, forgot to mention that managed bean is in session scope, there is no problem getting the id and storing it. Could you please extend on what you mean by passing parameter on the page on server? I am sort of newbie, so my knowledge is quite limited atm.

Answer (score 0):

So, after some digging into BI Publisher, found out that parameter can just be passed through url and to iframe. In other words, url should look somewhat like this: "content:port?accessmode&credentials&parameterid".